# Python / SupProcess / SqlCmd / using -v switch to pass variable

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlcmd

Trying really hard to use the -v switch to pass a variable to a SQL script (Python), but can't seem to get the syntax correct. I get the following error:

(Note how it looses the C: from the argument and appends a closing backslash)

**[stdout]  Sqlcmd: ':\Users\Public\MyProj\Tests\WorkingFolder\Database\"': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.**

On the server end, here is my syntax:

```
FILENAME = N'$(LOCATION)\MyDatabase.mdf'
```

Below is my code

```
        _varText = 'LOCATION="C:\\Users\\Public\\MyProj\\Tests\WorkingFolder\\Database"'       
        command_process = SubP.Popen(['sqlcmd','-b', '-E', '-S', _server, '-v', _varText , '-d', _database, '-i', filepath],
                                stdin = SubP.PIPE, stdout = SubP.PIPE, stderr = SubP.STDOUT, shell = True)
```

Comment: Holy crapola -- I finally had to do a work around (for anyone reading this later). On the python end, I replace the colon with a token (I chose "{col}", then do the reverse replace on the T-SQL end. It ain't pretty but it gets me there. The problem seems to be with sending a colon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
_varText = 'LOCATION=\"C:\\Users\\Public\\MyProj\\Tests\WorkingFolder\\Database\"'
```

It is based on recommendation in this section: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows

Comment: Thank you so very much - however that doesn't fix it...I still get the same error. One thing that I have learned since yesterday was that the problem appears to be with the ":". Anytime I pass a variable with a colon, it drops off the leading text.

Comment: ...Also, I don't think that you want to escape the double quote in your example, as it is inside a single quote.